# Convert easyar_Image to CIImage

Tags: objective-c, swift, ciimage, easyar

I've embedded code from EasyAR's HelloARVideo demo app (which is written in Objective-C) in my Swift project. AR works great and now I need to add QR code scanning feature. QR scanning was removed from EasyAR in version 3 and so I am thinking to process image frames manually and using system CIDetector  for QR recognition. Can you explain how to convert easyar_Image object to CIImage for further use in CIDetector? It can be done in Objective-C or Swift. Pixel format is YUV_NV12.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not use EasyAR, so I just guess something here.

As you say, pixel format is YUV_NV12.

So I guess it is a imageBuffer or pixelBuffer.

The way you can do is change imageBuffer/pixelBuffer to UIImage and than change it to CIImage.